# OOP vs procedural programming on arduino

Tags: programming, c++, code-optimization

It seems like the majority of Arduino applications are written without using classes / objects. Is there a reason for this? Does is slow down the Arduino or somehow present undesirable behavior?

Comment: Please note that "functional programming" is not what you think it is, I guess you wanted to say "procedural programming".

Comment: Functional programming usually involves the use of [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)), in languages that support them. C++ doesn't, and you would probably use [functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object) instead.

Comment: Check out [this article](http://hackaday.com/2015/11/06/code-craft-embedding-c-classes/). It explains the neglegable performance effect of using classes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your assumption is quite wrong:

- The majority of libraries use OOP.
- The majority of in-built device drivers use OOP.
- The core is filled with many OOP helper objects and classes.
- 99.99% of all sketches use those OOP objects.

The sketches themselves may not be written as a class or set of classes for a number of reasons:

1. There is no point
2. The programmer doesn't know how

When a sketch is just stitching together calls to objects defined through libraries and making a few decisions there is little point in making the sketch itself an object. It's just a waste of time.  In general if the sketch gets too complex to manage it gets broken down into smaller units - i.e., libraries - which are very often written as classes.

The moment you do `Serial.begin(9600);` you are using OOP.

Comment: Is there more than one `Serial` object? If not, what's the difference between `Serial.begin` and (hypothetically) `Serial_begin`?

Comment: On some boards yes there are multiple Serial objects.

Comment: If OOP is using C++ classes for implementation then this answer is fine. A more detailed answer may be found by first reading Peter Wegner's paper; http://www.cse.msu.edu/~stire/cse891/wegner.pdf. Arduino would be OOP if interfaces/classes would be more encapsulated, reused and extended.

Comment: You mean like Cosa? ;)

Comment: Hard to miss :)